# Drag item to the next page on android

Tags: java, android, xml

I have a viewpager including 3 pages. I set one viewgroup in each page and each of them has 4 items. Now I want to hold and drag one item from this page to another one.I already dealt with draging Item to the corner of the page but when moving to the new page, the new Item is not dragged. Is there any way to handle this problem?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't implemented drag and drop before so this might not work but perhaps you could make an invisible overlay view like a framelayout on top of the viewpager. Then handle all drag and drop coordination on this view.